# how to display the uploaded file contents on the same page without refreshing?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have the following html and php codes to read a uploaded file in a html page and display its contents in another new page, but i want the display the file contents in the same html page without opening a new tab and refreshing, how can I achieve that ?

**HTML:**

```
<html>
    <body>

        <form action="upload_file.php" method="post"
              enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label for="file">Filename:</label>
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

**PHP:upload_file.php**

```
<?php
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
        echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
        echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
        echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
        echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    }
?>
```

Comment: This cannot be done with php alone, you have to use javascript for this and make ajax calls. It is not complex, you just have to change your thinking a bit. Start reading about AJAX requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use iframe

**html**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            function ajaxFileUpload(upload_field)
            {   
                var filename = upload_field.value;
                upload_field.form.action = 'upload_file.php';
                upload_field.form.target = 'upload_iframe';
                upload_field.form.submit();     

                return true;
            }
        </script>
        <iframe name="upload_iframe" id="upload_iframe" ></iframe>

        <form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label for="file">Filename:</label>

            <input type="file" name="file" id="file" onchange="return ajaxFileUpload(this);">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**upload_file.php**

```
 <?php
     if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
     {
         echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
     }
     else
     {
         echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
         echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
         echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
         echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]. " <br>";
         $content = file_get_contents($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);

         echo "Content: ".$content; 
     }
   ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether the submit button is clicked or not using php and then proceeding to display the data.

PHP: upload.php

```
<?php
    //checks if the submit button is submitted
    if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == "Submit") {
        if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
            echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
        }
        else {
            echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
            echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
            echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
            echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
        }
    }
?>
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label for="file">Filename:</label>
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: but i want to display the data in the same page, with the above code also it is not possible

Comment: @Sachin it does display the data in the same page or do you mean without refreshing?